# Compiling issues with VS and DotNet 3.0 unexpected Error CS0023

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, .net-core, model-view-controller

I refactoring an application and have upgraded from core 2.2 to 3.0 and all of sudden I'm getting Compiler Error CS0023 codes when I build

I have never seen this issues before does anyone have a solution?

```
Error   CS0023  Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'Task<bool>'  .Web    \Navigation\Default.cshtml  7   Active
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool>' to 'bool .Web    Navigation\SideNav.cshtml   2   Active
Error   CS0023  Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'Task<bool>'  .Web    \Components\Navigation\SideNav.cshtml   9   Active
Error   CS0023  Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'Task<bool>'  .Web    Shared\Components\Navigation\SideNav.cshtml 13  Active
Error   CS1977  Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type. .Web    \Details.cshtml 8   Active
Error   CS1973  'IHtmlHelper<dynamic>' has no applicable method named 'RenderPartialAsync' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.    .Web    Details.cshtml  132 Active
Error   CS1973  'IHtmlHelper<dynamic>' has no applicable method named 'RenderPartialAsync' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.    A.Web   Details.cshtml  171 Active
```

Comment: Hi, @ devcraw.
The error log points out where the error occurred, you could check the code in the following places and try to solve the problem:
Line 7 of the \Navigation\Default.cshtml file.
Line 2, Line 9 and Line 13 of the Navigation\SideNav.cshtml file.
Line 8, line 132 and line 171 of the Details.cshtml.
If there is any problem, please show me the code of the related problem (the code I mentioned above) to analyze the issue.

Comment: I found the fix. you need add <RazorCompileOnBuild>false</RazorCompileOnBuild>
   <RazorCompileOnPublish>false</RazorCompileOnPublish> to the cs prog and .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
 to the startup file